# Jmeter - Changing values per environment

Tags: jmeter

I have a situation in jmeter while running the endpoint url keeps changing.

for example:
URL1 [QA]: Facebook/v1/account2
URL1 [dev]: Facebook/account

Some times end point url is changing but my scripts are same. How do I handle the end point change for the above conditions?

Comment: what exactly are you testing. May be there is a different way to do this

Comment: Show where exactly you need to change, is it for HTTP request Path field?

Comment: it is an https request

Comment: it is simple we have 2 environments Development & QA. when we run the script using development the URL "https://Facebook/account                        when we run same scripts in QA there is a URL change , QA URL "https://Facebook/v1/account2. so how do we handle URL change by using regular expressions?  I hope my question is clear now

Answer (score 0):

You should use different property values for qa and dev

You can simply send different value in command line -J

```
 jmeter -Jpath=Facebook/v1/account2 -t your.jmx
```

And then in Path field get path property value using __P function:

```
 ${__P(path)}
```

If you have multiple properties you can add different property files using -q, e.g.:

```
  jmeter -q dev.properties -t your.jmx
```

And your dev.properties will be

```
 path=Facebook/v1/account2
```

Comment: tried this option  jmeter -Jpath=Facebook/v1/account2 -t your.jmx  it worked . thank you so much for the help

Comment: @vasudeva you can accept the answer by clicking V sign to the left