# JMetter how to change stringProp user_define_classpath from command-line

Tags: command-line, jmeter

I made a performace test with JMeter, and then I call it from command-line.

```
jmeter -t PerformanceTests.jmx
```

Inside the file 'PerformanceTests.jmx' I need to conditionaly  change a 'stringProp' to set the value of 'user_define_classpath' from command-line

[image]

Is this possible? I already googled but no success...

Comment: Use property as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58546799/jmeter-changing-values-per-environment/58553990?r=SearchResults#58553990

Answer (score 1):

As per [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) user manual entry you can amend `user.classpath` property and add your .jar file(s) there like:

```
jmeter -Juser.classpath=c:/tests/libs/cassandra-driver-core-3.3.0.jar -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

In order to make the change permanent add the above line to *user.properites* file:

```
user.classpath=c:/tests/libs/cassandra-driver-core-3.3.0.jar
```

In 2nd case JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)